# How do I ensure my DispatchQueue executes some code on the main thread specifically?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have a singleton that manages an array. This singleton can be accessed from multiple threads, so it has its own internal `DispatchQueue` to manage read/write access across threads. For simplicity we'll say it's a serial queue.

There comes a time where the singleton will be reading from the array and updating the UI. How do I handle this?

Which thread my internal dispatch queue is not known, right? It's just an implementation detail I'm to not worry about? In most cases this seems fine, but in this one specific function I need to be sure it uses the main thread.

Is it okay to do something along the lines of:

```swift
myDispatchQueue.sync { // Synchronize with internal queue to ensure no writes/reads happen at the same time
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // Ensure that it's executed on the main thread
        for item in internalArray {
            // Pretend internalArray is an array of strings
            someLabel.text = item
        }
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is that okay? It seems weird/wrong to be nesting dispatch queues. Is there a better way? Maybe something like `myDispatchQueue.sync(forceMainThread: true) { ... }`?
2. If I DID NOT use `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`, and I called the function from the main thread, could I be sure that my internal dispatch queue will execute it on the same (main) thread as what called it? Or is that also an "implementation detail" where it could be, but it could also be called on a background thread?

Basically I'm confused that threads seem like an implementation detail you're not supposed to worry about with queues, but what happens on the odd chance when you DO need to worry?

Simple example code:

```swift
class LabelUpdater {
    static let shared = LabelUpdater()

    var strings: [String] = []
    private let dispatchQueue: dispatchQueue

    private init {
        dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.sample.me.LabelUpdaterQueue")
        super.init()
    }

    func add(string: String) {
        dispatchQueue.sync {
            strings.append(string)
        }
    }

    // Assume for sake of example that `labels` is always same array length as `strings`
    func updateLabels(_ labels: [UILabel]) {
        // Execute in the queue so that no read/write can occur at the same time.
        dispatchQueue.sync {
            // How do I know this will be on the main thread? Can I ensure it?
            for (index, label) in labels.enumerated() {
                label.text = strings[index]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your thread-safe singleton so we can take a look at it.

Comment: To answer your question, nesting dispatch queues is mandatory when you need to execute some part of a background task on the main thread. The concept of your example code is standard practice. How I would actually implement it is something else.

Comment: Stop worrying about threads and think about queues?

Comment: @matt How do I stop worrying about threads when I'm using queues and the single most parroted line in iOS development is "never update the UI on the main thread"?

Comment: In that one case they are effectively synonyms. Indeed, it is safe to call `isMainThread` to find out if you are on the main queue already.

Comment: @bsod I updated it with a little example

Comment: @matt And if it returns `false`? Effectively I'm wondering if A) I call the function on the main thread, will the dispatch queue respect that? B) If not, should I/is it allowed to wrap it in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` to ensure it is?

Comment: I don’t know what “respect” means but I think the answer is yes and yes. However I am skeptical that you would ever not know what queue you called your own method on.

Comment: @matt "Respect" meaning if the `dispatchQueue.sync` is invoked on, say, Thread 4, will it also always execute the block on Thread 4, or will it potentially move to a different thread? Situations where you're unsure of what queue called the method on would be if it can potentially be called from iOS networking functions that return on a background thread, I would want to ensure it's called from the main thread.

Comment: But “if it can potentially be called from iOS networking functions that return on a background thread” it would be that function’s job to call it on the main thread, just as it would do to talk to the interface.

Comment: @matt That's precisely what I'm asking, if that iOS networking function A makes sure it calls the function B on the main thread/queue, is it guaranteed that the function B's dispatch queue is called on the main thread as well? Or do I need to go out of my way to ensure it? My assumption is the latter, as my understanding of GCD seems to be that it allocates tasks to threads as needed internally in a way that's opaque.

Comment: I do not know what “is it guaranteed that the function B's dispatch queue is called on the main thread as well” even means. If you call a method on a certain queue it is called on that queue, obviously.

Comment: @matt Take this code for instance: `DispatchQueue.main.async { DispatchQueue(label: "test.test.test2", attributes: .concurrent).async { print("Hello world") } }` is the print of "Hello world" guaranteed to be executed from the main thread, or does the internal DispatchQueue create its own threading logic?

Comment: “the print of "Hello world" guaranteed to be executed from the main thread” What?? It is guaranteed to be executed from the dispatch queue test.test.test2.

Comment: @matt ... yes, that much is clear. I'm simply asking in terms of threads, is the THREAD guaranteed to be the main one, or does the queue potentially spin up its own thread?

Comment: Of course a non main queue spins up its own non main thread.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm glad it's obvious to you but the clarification was appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can nest a dispatch to one queue inside a dispatch to another queue. We frequently do so.

But be very careful. Just wrapping an asynchronous dispatch to the main queue with a dispatch from your synchronizing queue is insufficient. Your first example is not thread safe. That array that you are accessing from the main thread might be mutating from your synchronization queue:

[image]

This is a [race condition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/thread_sanitizer/races_on_collections_and_other_apis) because you potentially have multiple threads (your synchronization queue’s thread and the main thread) interacting with the same collection. Rather than having your dispatched block to the main queue just interact `objects` directly, you should make a copy of of it, and that’s what you reference inside the dispatch to the main queue.

For example, you might want to do the following:

```
func process(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    syncQueue.sync {
        let result = ...            // note, this runs on thread associated with `syncQueue` ...

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(result)      // ... but this runs on the main thread
        }
    }
}
```

That ensures that the main queue is not interacting with any internal properties of this class, but rather just the `result` that was created in this closure passed to `syncQueue`.

---

Note, all of this is unrelated to it being a singleton. But since you brought up the topic, I’d advise against singletons for model data. It’s fine for sinks, stateless controllers, and the like, but not generally advised for model data.

I’d definitely discourage the practice of initiating UI controls updates directly from the singleton. I’d be inclined to provide these methods completion handler closures, and let the caller take care of the resulting UI updates. Sure, if you want to dispatch the closure to the main queue (as a convenience, common in many third party API), that’s fine. But the singleton shouldn’t be reaching in and update UI controls itself.

I’m assuming you did all of this just for illustrative purposes, but I added this word of caution to future readers who might not appreciate these concerns.

Comment: What if there's not really a result to pass? To elaborate more on my specific use case (as you guessed I mostly made up examples) it's to do with theming the app, where essentially a bunch of `listener` objects (UIViews, UIViewControllers, etc. that adopt a protocol) get informed of a theme change and then a protocol is called on them letting them update. There's no return value for this, it's fire and forget. But I need to synchronize between new listeners being added (write) and notifying all (read) of them (which must happen on main thread) due to UIKit.

Comment: I don’t get the question: If there’s no value to pass, then just define your closure to not take any parameters, e.g. `() -> Void` and dispatch that to the main queue. Or rather than building your own observation system, many use `NotificationCenter` and [add observers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver), specifying the `.main` operation queue.

Comment: There are values to pass, the `listeners` array (what I meant was I don't receive a value from the closure). This array is essentially looped through and each listener is notified and told to update its theme. This has to be done on the main thread, but I also have to ensure that `listeners` isn't written to while this is occurring. My naive solution would be something like `myDispatchQueue.sync { DispatchQueue.main.async { self.listeners.forEach { $0.theme() } } }` which I'm assuming wouldn't work?

Comment: The idea’s fine, but it’s not thread safe. Create a copy of that `listeners` array and use that copy inside the `...main.async` closure.

Comment: Oh! Good idea! This is probably a dumb question, but with a Swift array of UIViewControllers and passing by reference rather than value and whatnot, is it sufficient to do a `let listenersCopy = self.listeners` prior to the `main.async` closure?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. You need copy of the array, not of the view controllers. Note, you might want to make sure your `listeners` isn’t preventing your view controllers from being deallocated, if you haven’t already.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **OperationQueues(Operations)** as they do have states:

- **isReady**: It’s prepared to start
- **isExecuting**: The task is currently running
- **isFinished**: Once the process is completed
- **isCancelled**: The task canceled

**Operation Queues  benefits:**

- Determining Execution Order
- observe their states
- Canceling Operations

> Operations can be paused, resumed, and cancelled. Once you dispatch a
>   task using Grand Central Dispatch, you no longer have control or
>   insight into the execution of that task. The NSOperation API is more
>   flexible in that respect, giving the developer control over the
>   operation’s life cycle

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue

https://medium.com/@aliakhtar_16369/concurrency-in-swift-operations-and-operation-queue-part-3-a108fbe27d61